# .lib file that comes with a TV I bought on AliExpress

Tags: windows, video, avi, .lib

I bought a small tv on AliExpress which is meant to play video files.
It connects to my Windows PC and I can browse the internal memory card.
I transferred some .avi files but they do not play when i turn on the tv.

There is a .lib file in the internal memory buy I can't open it.

Any ideas?
Thanks#
P